# UITableView Slow to load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an UIViewController with an UITableView inside him, I draw the items inside my Table using the Interface (Drag and drop Labels, and UITextViews) my table have 25 rows.

Now it's time to link my labels with IBOutlets for this I create a Subclass of TableViewCell Like this:

**TableViewCell.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
```

**TableViewCell.m**

```
@synthesize label1 = _label1;
```

And I use this code for change my first label:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    HobbiesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[HobbiesTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }


    cell.label1.text = @"GG";

    return cell;
}
```

But I saw a little problem, When I open my View (in simulator) is too slow to open (I think my table is loading), for try to solve this problem I delete the `nonatomic` of my property and my View open faster.

But I have one question, When I create Properties I always put the command `nonatomic`, and in this project I had to take it off because the slowness, have a problem to take off the `nonatomic` in this property?(Since the labels will never be changed!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `label1` weak, as it is is in Storyboard. You also don't need to `@synthesize` anymore.

Also, if you are dequeuing with different identifiers, you are really not dequeueing. Prototype cells should have one identifier in storyboard.

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCellID"
 HobbiesTableViewCell *cell = [tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Nonatomic should increase performance, and is not causing your problem.

Comment: Yes my cell have identifiers in storyboard, Now I will put (weak, retain) or (nonatomic, weak) inside my property?

Comment: @LettersBa, in addition to what was said, you'd better use nonatomic as there's only one thread that's going to interact with your IBOutlet - the main thread.

Comment: @LettersBa, weak and retain (strong nowadays) are mutual exclusive. You should end up with (weak, nonatomic).

Comment: @LettersBA If you are using one UITableViewCell class, it needs to have one and only one prototype cell in storyboard. That one cell ID is what you use to dequeue.

Comment: I use now (weak, nonatomic) and the result is slow, strange, If I use only (weak) I don't need to synthesize and is more faster...

Comment: In my case I have 25 cells in my table, and I use only one class (UITableViewCell) with different properties (labels1, labels2, labels3) and the prototype cells in my table all of 25 is subclass of this class that I create

Comment: You don't need to synthesize anyway. you don't want to keep a strong reference to every label in the tableview. See my code above. on dequeuing.

Comment: You could use different types of cells and use different cell identifiers. May be you are doing something on the cells that make them load slower than it should.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>From what you have listed, I would rather blame not the table view, but the way you fill `menuItems`. Does its contents come from the internet or a file? If yes, I guess the problem is that you perform access to a remote data source on the main thread</strike>.

UPD:
After a short talk with the PO it became clear the the issue was because of having 25 cells with different Reuse ID's.

Comment: My MenuItems contains an array of identifiers (cell), like this = @"1",@"2"...@"25"

Comment: The problem is that you have 1 identifier per cell - you're actually not reusing anything. That is the cause of the lag.

Comment: I've started a chat. Visit http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91183/room-for-arthur-gevorkyan-and-lettersba